# HTML5 Video File Size issues

Tags: html, video

How do web devs shrink their video files? Nearly every new website these days plays a massive full screen video on repeat at page load and it loads pretty much instantly with absolutely no buffering required (and I'm on crappy internet), so the file size would have to be tiny (a few MB's at most and by a few I mean 3).

But I took a 43 second screencast using CamStudio of my desktop and it is 154MB. I clipped the video to show only the parts I needed, which brought it down to 120MB in size.

It makes no sense.

How can I use HTML5 Video and tiny file sizes? I don't see how video files can be as small as they need to be for websites - but it is possible because I've seen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to buffer the whole video to watch it.
A video is on a server, and you load only a few seconds of a video at the same time.
So for a 43sec video, that does 120MB You're going to load like 3sec per 3sec, which means approximately 9MB per 9MB.

If you're host it on your computer, it will take so much more time than if you host it on youtube or vimeo.

Answer (score 1):

WEBM files are good for this. it is a format especially for web. small and good quality. Try to convert your file to this format